# How to create lists by running functions in parallel in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I want to create two lists by running two functions (returning a value each for every run) in parallel. My code below works, but is still taking too much time. Is there a more efficient way to parallelize this code?

```
import time
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
 
catchments = 50   #define number of catchments to plot here
randomlist = random.sample(range(2, 2100), catchments)

def budx(i):   #Time-taking task....
    try:        
        catch = slicecatch(i)
        return catch.PETNatVeg.mean().values/catch.Prec.mean().values
    except IndexError as e:
        pass    
        
def budy(i):   #Time-taking task....
    try:        
        catch = slicecatch(i)
        return catch.TotalET.mean().values/catch.Prec.mean().values
    except IndexError as e:
        pass 
    
        
 
start_time = time.perf_counter()

bud_x = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(budx)(i) for i in randomlist)
bud_y = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(budy)(i) for i in randomlist) 

finish_time = time.perf_counter()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've written your code, you're first running all your `budx` instances, waiting for them to complete, and only then running your `budy` instances. That is, you are sequentially running two sets of parallel tasks.

Here's one possible way of doing that, noting that (a) I was not previously familiar with joblib, so there may be a more canonical form, and (b) I've replaced your `budx` and `budy` implementations with code that I can actually run:

```
import time
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import random
 
catchments = 50   #define number of catchments to plot here
randomlist = random.sample(range(2, 2100), catchments)

def budx(i):   #Time-taking task....
    print("start budx", i)
    time.sleep(random.randint(0, 10))
    print("end budx", i)
    return ("budx", i)

def budy(i):   #Time-taking task....
    print("start budy", i)
    time.sleep(random.randint(0, 10))
    print("end budy", i)
    return ("budy", i)
 
start_time = time.perf_counter()

results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(
        [delayed(budx)(i) for i in range(5)] +
        [delayed(budy)(i) for i in range(5)])

finish_time = time.perf_counter()

print("total time:", finish_time - start_time)
print("results", results)
```

If I were writing this I would probably opt for native Python tools like `concurrent.futures` rather than a third-party module like `joblib` (unless there are additional features provided by `joblib` that make your life easier).

Comment: Thank you larsks! Your improvement certainly helps and the code is several times faster now :)